# Shifting hex value left and the most-significant bit should disappear (or lost) using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have hex values (8-bit length) which I want to shift to the left and the leading significant bit should disappear. But I did not find an easy way to do it.

Here are some examples.

```
h = hex(0xFF << 1)
print h
```

Output_1: `0x1fe`

```
h = hex(0xFF << 2)
print h
```

Output_2: `0x3fc`

```
h = hex(0xFF << 3)
print h
```

Output_3: `0x7f8`

However, I am expecting the MSB should disappear and the hex value remains in 8-bit length. The expected output must be like this:

Output_1: `0xfe`

Output_2: `0xfc`

Output_3: `0xf8`

Can anyone please help me on this?

Comment: You mean 8-bit? Also, do you know about the bitwise AND (`&`) operator?

Comment: yes, I mean 8-bit length, I am sorry for the mistake. I know bitwise AND operation.

Comment: Why do you have python 3 and python 2 in your tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I did not get any reply for my ques. However, as a beginner, I came up with the below code:

```
h = '0xFF'
count = 0
for i in range(0, 8, 1):
    y = int(h, 16)
    count = count + (2**i)
    y = 255 - count             ## 255 is decimal value of 0xFF
    print hex(y)
```

Output:

0xfe

0xfc

0xf8

0xf0

0xe0

0xc0

0x80

0x0

This is the output, I was looking for.